# How to read strings from HDF5 dataset using h5py

Tags: python, python-3.x, hdf5, h5py

I have a HDF5 file which `h5dump`s as follows (omitting irrelevant content)

```
HDF5 "file.h5" {
GROUP "/" {
  DATASET "history" {
    DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
      STRSIZE H5T_VARIABLE;
      STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
      CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
      CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
    }
    DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 1 ) / ( H5S_UNLIMITED ) }
    DATA {
    (0): "some string"
    }
  }
}
```

and which I'm trying to read from python (3.5) using h5py. My attempt so far is

```
import h5py
F = h5py.File('file.h5', "r")
H = list()
for x in F['history']:
    H.append(str(x))
```

but

```
for x in H:
    print(x)
```

produces

```
b'some string'
```

instead of simply

```
some string
```

How can I extract the pure data string? What do I need to do instead of `str(x)`?

P.S. This is my first python question, so please bear with me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use

```
H = [x.decode() for x in F['history']]
```

This list comprehension will return `H` as a list of strings.